# Why the sum of quantity differs for the same file in excel and power bi?

Tags: excel, powerbi

I have a table **2019 Q1**. [This is the link for the excel file](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1kVI7R4VHwWvxarWteh4Iq7AEtn2kFDcf/edit?usp=sharing&ouid=111786840706330555618&rtpof=true&sd=true). the sum of **QTY**  column in excel is 1071629 but in power bi it is 2M.

For Power BI, I selected a card and dragged the QTY column into the card. It summed up the QTY value as 2M which is not correct.

Where am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That workbook has filters set in Excel which Power BI doesn't respect.  You can filter the rows in Power Query if you want.